# Oracle-asm RHEL 5 Kernel Upgrade Instructions?

Tags: rhel5, linux-kernel, oracle-asm

What are the official instructions for upgrading the oracle-asm kernel drivers when performing a kernel update on RHEL 5? I can only find documentation on a clean install of oracle-asm which includes configuration. But its my understanding is that I have to:

1. Shut down ASM and disable auto start of ASM upon boot
2. Patch the kernel and reboot
3. Download the kernel matching oracle-asm RPM package and install
4. Make sure oracleasm-support and oracleasmlib RPMs are on the latest release
5. Startup ASM and re-enable auto start
6. Reboot to make sure ASM comes up on its own.

No further configuration is needed right? Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked of Oracle support

Answer (score -2, accepted):

FYI.. Contacted Oracle Support, they verified this is the correct process..